# How can I make current ViewController not releasable?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

IS there way to do it? I have MapViewCOntroller and I not want to init it every time.

Comment: can you show some source code of where you are init'ing it every time? how do you keep track of it?

Comment: create a single shared instance of your view controller in the appdelegate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution would be, add a dictionary in you AppDelegate class. Add all your controllers to that dictionary with key as controller name. Add helper methods which will return viewController based on the key passed. By this way you can keep track of all your View Controllers in one dictionary.

Add a dictionary like this in your AppDelegate :

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableDictionary *viewControllers;
```

Add helper methods like this :

```
- (void)setViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController forKey:(NSString *)vcKey
{
    if( !self.viewControllers )
    {
       self.viewControllers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }

    [self.viewControllers setObject:viewController forKey:vcKey];
}


- (UIViewController *)viewControllerWithKey:(NSString *)vcKey
{
   return [self.viewControllers objectForKey:vcKey];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your AppDelegate.h declare a property like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) YourViewController *vc;
```

In AppDelegate.m files `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
self.vc = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];
```

After that from any ViewController you can do this:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

The you can get the vc of AppDelegate by writing this: `appDelegate.vc`

Hope this helps.. :)